# MATLAB - No SURF features detected in uint16 images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, surf, image-registration

I am using SURF features for image registration. I have images of type `uint16`.

`pts1 = detectSURFFeatures(image)`

When I used the above function on `uint16` images, the function returned 0 SURF points. As a workaround, I used to convert the images to `uint8`, after which the function was returning a good amount of detected SURF points. Thus, the function worked on `uint8` images, but not on `uint16`.

Note, that the function doesn't show any error. It executes successfully, but the `SURFPoints object` returned has 0 SURFPoints.

Why does this happen? The [documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectsurffeatures.html#bs39_qf-3) of the above function says that the image can be `single, double, uint8, uint16, int16 and logical`. Then why is the function not working on the `uint16` images I am using?

I experimented by converting the image to `double` data type. It didn't work. It worked only when I convert the image to `uint8`.

Sorry I cannot share the images since they are confidential data, but did anybody here faced similar issues?

I could have continued with the conversion to `uint8`, but that is posing some other problem, hence I want to know the solution to the fundamental issue.

I am using MATLAB 2017.

Comment: try a different threshold value, hope it works !!!

Comment: converting the image to double as `im2double()` did not work? Remember, double images need to be scaled [0-1], just casting to double is not enough.

Comment: @user8190410 I tried different threshold values. Sadly, it didn't work.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried converting to `double` again, simply by doing `double(img)`. Surprisingly, this time it worked. I must have done something else wrong previously or must have missed something. Also, I used `im2double(img)`, but with that, again no `SURFPoints` were detected. Do you have any explanation of why points are getting detected in some datatypes?

Comment: No because I can not read the source code. The most likely thing is the expected range of the data types, maybe SURF assumes you get in an image with specific scale. But it is just a guess. If you want more info you may get it if you provide a [mcve]